# How to replace existing Python thread when duplicate is instantiated?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, pyzmq

On a Flask app, I have a URL route for invoking a python thread via:

```
@mod.route('/api/start-zmq-listener')
def startZMQListener():
    try:
        # get new user profile
        userProfile = user.findUser('test')

        thread = threading.Thread(target=enableZMQ, kwargs={
            'username': userProfile['username'],
            'userEmail': userProfile['email'],
            'userPhone': userProfile['phone'],
            'notifications': userProfile['notifications']
        })

        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
        print (threading.enumerate())

        return success_response('ok')

    except Exception as e:
        return error_response(e)
```

This invokes the "enableZMQ" function:

```
def enableZMQ(username, userEmail, userPhone, notifications):

    while True:
        etc...
```

I want the existing "enableZMQ" while loop (run as a daemon) to update with new userProfile information each time it's invoked. However, when I put "enableZMQ()" in the "startZMQListener()" route, it merely creates a duplicate and they are both run concurrently, which messes things up.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do here. You have a function called "enableZMQ" that takes some user details. Why does that function start with a while-true loop? Why do you have an `'existing "enableZMQ" while loop (run as a daemon)'`? What is the `enableZMQ ` function actually expected to do?

Comment: Let's say enableZMQ just prints out username, userEmail, userPhone, and notifications. However, the route, startZMQListener gets new user info each time its called.

Comment: Ok, but then it doesn't make sense why there is a `while True:` loop at the top of it, and it's still not clear why you have an `'existing "enableZMQ" while loop (run as a daemon)'`?